# Se descarga un archivo cuando accedo a mi página wordpress

Tags: php, wordpress

Cuando intento ingresar a mi página wordpress en mi hosting se descarga un archivo, con este código dentro:

```
<?php
/**
 * Front to the WordPress application. This file doesn't do anything, but loads
 * wp-blog-header.php which does and tells WordPress to load the theme.
 *
 * @package WordPress
 */

/**
 * Tells WordPress to load the WordPress theme and output it.
 *
 * @var bool
 */
define( 'WP_USE_THEMES', true );

/** Loads the WordPress Environment and Template */
require __DIR__ . '/wp-blog-header.php';
```

Además he reiniciado el hosting de nuevo, he instalado todo nuevamente y pasa lo mismo.

Este error no me permite ni entrar en wp-admin

Pd: Esto me pasó luego de cambiar de hosting, en el "antiguo" funcionaba correctamente con la misma base de datos, aplicación y .htaccess.

Comment: falta instalar o configurar php, te está leyendo el archivo como "de texto", que servidor web es? en apache necesitas o mod_php o php-fpm

Comment: ¿Se descarga como archivo con extensión `.php`? ¿Cambiaste también de dominio o migraste todo al nuevo hosting, dominio incluido? ¿Modificaste algún archivo de WP a mano, como `wp-config.php`? ¿En qué directorio del hosting tienes WP instalado?

Comment: Alo Malbarez no creo que falte php, ya que tengo otra aplicación en el hosting con php 7.4, puede que sea que lo está leyendo como texto aunque no sabría como solucionarlo, es un hosting compartido con cpanel, no comprendo lo de que en apache necesito mod_php o php-fpm.

Comment: A. Cedano, no es un archivo `.php`, dice que es tipo Archivo, lo migré con el dominio anterior, lo que si es un "Dominio adicional", aunque así lo tenía en el hosting anterior, modifiqué el `wp-config.php` claramente para importar la bd, tengo instalado el wp en ej: `public_html/WP`. De antemano muchas gracias.

Comment: seguramente haya que configurar php para el dominio adicional, eso que ves como texto es el [`index.php` de wordpress](https://github.com/WordPress/WordPress/blob/master/index.php)

Comment: mod_php y php-fpm son dos formas de ejecutar código php, el primero es un módulo de apache y por lo general se autoconfigura al instalarse, el segundo al ser un servidor fastcgi ( apache hace de proxy para los archivos php ) tal vez necesite un retoque para que sepa donde está la carpeta base o en que puerto está el fpm

Answer (score 0):

Cambia tu .htaccess por esto

```
# BEGIN WordPress
<IfModule mod_rewrite.c>
RewriteEngine On
RewriteBase /
RewriteRule ^index\.php$ - [L]
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteRule . /index.php [L]
</IfModule>
# END WordPress
```

Y verifica si el problema persiste, no olvides hacer una copia de seguridad de tu .htaccess primero, aveces el problema puede ser por el htacces del sitio, esto lo que hace es reestablecerlo a su estado por defecto.

Comment: Y eso que hace? Podrías mejorar tu respuesta al mejorar tu explicación del código.